# Is there a way to iterate a function for each element of a large list in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, roc, iterated-function

I would like to perform a ROC curve analysis using the pROC package in R.
I have a dataset (dataframe) of 45 subjects; each one of them has about 1000 values in a column called "spike_conn" that should predict my categorial variable "Resected" (another column in the dataframe).

I have created a large list of 45 dataframes using the split function like this:

```
 list_data <- split(database_all, database_all$patient)
```

Then I have tried to use a for loop to perform the roc curve function for each element of the list (45 dataframes) like this:

```
Results_list <- list()
for (p in list_data) {
  rocbj <- lapply(p, roc(list_data[[]][,29], list_data[[]][,5]))  
  Results_list[p] <- rocbj$auc
}
```

But it seems to be wrong, can somebody help? Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you trying to produce one `roc` object for each of the 45 subjects?  Is the dataset approximately 45000 rows (~1000 rows per subject?) . You may benefit from the guidance on asking questions on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).

Comment: You can apply a function to each element of a `list` with `lapply`, as in `lapply(your_list, your_function)`. It's not clear what that title question has to do with the question in your text - I'd suggest making a reproducible example with a little bit of sample input presented in a copy/pasteable format and a more detailed description of what you want to do - perhaps with some sample code of your best attempt so far.